# Confusing instructions for regular Governance Registry and Clustering Governance Registry

Tags: database, installation, wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

So I'm working in setting up an alternate, supported DB to MySQL for my Governance Registry and do so for multiple instances for cluster and I'm completely confused at how to properly setup the database structure itself.

From an initial install of Governance Registry, the master-datasources.xml is structured one way (WSO2CARBON_DB, WSO2AM_DB, BAM_STATS_DB, and ES_STORAGE) and the Cluster Governance Registry instructions require another way with MySQL-only entries (governancedb, WSO2_AM_DB, WSO2_USER_DB, WSO2_CARBON_DB_mount, and WSO2_CARBON_DB).

I'm not sure which naming schema './wso2server.sh -Dsetup' command would use for its setup.

Which instructions would I follow to setting up my DB structure? I've also never come across BAM_STATS or ES_STORAGE before and I'm wondering what their purpose is for from the initial install. Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are clustering WSO2 Governance Registry, you need to have three databases for "WSO2_CARBON_DB_mount", "WSO2_USER_DB" and "[Social DB](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Governance+Registry+5.x.0#ClusteringGovernanceRegistry5.x.0-Sharingthesocialdatabase)". You can ignore other databases such as WSO2AM_DB, BAM_STATS_DB, etc.

So you can follow the instructions available in the "[Clustering Governance Registry 5.x.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Governance+Registry+5.x.0)" doc. There you can ignore WSO2AM_DB configuration steps.